# Finding phrase in specified files

Tags: c++, strings, file

Please provide constructive feedback so I can learn from my mistakes. Please tell me what I did right and where I came up with very good solution and where I should improve. Here is the code (Please pardon some indentation, formatting errors):

```
/*
Author: Filip Mirosław
Author's GitHub Account: https://github.com/Sproza
Purpose: To find requested phrase in specified files.
What you can do with this code:
PLease feel free to do whatever you like
with this piece of code (unless it is for bad purpose).
If you do not make major changes to the program
(only little tweaks) please remember to specify me as an author
of this code using github account(my name and surname is optional).
Also please provide link to the original code.
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
// !!!!!!!!!! SECTION GETTING AND PROCESSING USER'S INPUT !!!!!!!!!!

// Variable storing phrase to look for in the files.
string phrase;
cout << "Find: ";
getline(cin, phrase);
// Vector storing file names to look for a phrase.
vector <string> files;
cout << endl << "In: ";
string users_input;
getline(cin, users_input);

// Vector element to store first word.
files.push_back("");
// Variable used to iterate through vector's elements and add words to them.
int element = 0;
stringstream sstream;
for(int i = 0; i < users_input.size(); i++)
{
    if(users_input[i] != ' ')
    {
        // Variable to store users_input[i] stringified.
        string append_this;
        sstream << users_input[i];
        sstream >> append_this;
        files[element].append(append_this);
        sstream.str("");
        sstream.clear();
    }
    else
    {
        files.push_back("");
        element++;
    }
}

// !!!!!!!!!! SECTION LOOKING FOR A PHRASE IN THE FILES !!!!!!!!!!

vector <string> occurrences;
string line;
// Variable storing result of calling .find(phrase) function after casting to string.
string _find;
// Variable use as a second argument to function .find(phrase) descrbing
// index number of character at which to start looking for phrase.
int start_from = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++)
{
    ifstream file(files[i].c_str());
    if(!file)
    {
        cout << "Error opening a file: \"" << files[i] << "\"" << endl;
        continue;
    }
    occurrences.push_back("File: " + files[i]);
    string line_number = "1";
    int line_number_arithmetic;
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        getline(file, line);
        if(line.find(phrase) != -1)
        {
            occurrences.push_back("Line: " + line_number);
        }
        while(line.find(phrase, start_from) != -1)
        {
            sstream << line.find(phrase, start_from);
            sstream >> _find;
            sstream.str("");
            sstream.clear();
            occurrences.push_back(_find);
            start_from = line.find(phrase, start_from) + phrase.size();
        }
        if(line.find(phrase, start_from) == -1)
        {
                start_from = 0;
                sstream << line_number;
                sstream >> line_number_arithmetic;
                sstream.str("");
                sstream.clear();
                line_number_arithmetic += 1;
                sstream << line_number_arithmetic;
                sstream >> line_number;
                sstream.str("");
                sstream.clear();
        }

    }
    file.close();
}

// !!!!!!!!!! SECTION PRINTING OUT THE RESULTS OF THE SEARCH !!!!!!!!!!

cout << endl << endl << "Search Completed!" << endl << endl << "Full Report: " << endl;
int i = 0;
int number_of_occurrences = 0;
bool insert_coma = false;
while(i < occurrences.size())
{
    number_of_occurrences = 0;
    if((occurrences[i].at(0) == 'F') && (occurrences[i].at(1) == 'i') &&
    (occurrences[i].at(2) == 'l') && (occurrences[i].at(3) == 'e') &&
    (occurrences[i].at(4) == ':') && (occurrences[i].at(5) == ' '))
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < occurrences.size(); j++)
        {
            if(occurrences[j].find_first_not_of("0123456789") == -1)
            {
                number_of_occurrences++;
            }
            else if((occurrences[j].at(0) == 'F') && (occurrences[j].at(1) == 'i') &&
            (occurrences[j].at(2) == 'l') && (occurrences[j].at(3) == 'e') &&
            (occurrences[j].at(4) == ':') && (occurrences[j].at(5) == ' '))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        cout << endl << number_of_occurrences << " occurrences found in file ";
        occurrences[i].erase(0, 6);
        cout << "\"" << occurrences[i] << "\"";
        i++;
        insert_coma = false;
    }
    else if((occurrences[i].at(0) == 'L') && (occurrences[i].at(1) == 'i') &&
    (occurrences[i].at(2) == 'n') && (occurrences[i].at(3) == 'e') &&
    (occurrences[i].at(4) == ':') && (occurrences[i].at(5) == ' '))
    {
        occurrences[i].erase(0, 6);
        cout << endl << "\tLine: " << occurrences[i];
        i++;
        insert_coma = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if(insert_coma)
        {
            cout << ", " << occurrences[i];
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " Position: " << occurrences[i];
        }
        i++;
        insert_coma = true;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you really not indent your `main()`'s inside?

Comment: BTW: That's a nice [megamoth](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see a number of things which may help you improve your code.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Especially in a very simple program like this, there's little reason to use that line.  Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Fix your formatting

There are abundant examples here of C++ code that is well formatted.  This code has peculiar indentation that makes it difficult to tell when a function begins and ends.  Fixing that would help.

### Break up the code into smaller functions

The `main()` code is very long and does a series of identifiable steps.  Rather than having everything in one long function, it would be easier to read and maintain if each discrete step were its own function.

### Be careful with signed and unsigned

In the current code, the loop integers `i` and `j` are signed `int` values, but they're being compared with `unsigned` quantities `files.size()` and `occurrences.size()`, etc.  Better would be to declare them all as `unsigned` or perhaps `size_t`.

### Don't use `std::endl` if you don't really need it

The difference betweeen `std::endl` and `'\n'` is that `'\n'` just emits a newline character, while `std::endl` actually flushes the stream.  This can be time-consuming in a program with a lot of I/O and is rarely actually needed.  It's best to *only* use `std::endl` when you have some good reason to flush the stream and it's not very often needed for simple programs such as this one.  Avoiding the habit of using `std::endl` when `'\n'` will do will pay dividends in the future as you write more complex programs with more I/O and where performance needs to be maximized.

### Simplify by using standard algorithms

Here's a program that does most of what yours does, but in far fewer lines:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void search(const std::string &phrase, std::istream &in) {
    std::string line;
    for (unsigned linenum=1; getline(in, line); ++linenum) {
        for (auto pos=line.find(phrase); pos != std::string::npos; pos=line.find(phrase, ++pos) ) {
            std::cout << "\tLine: " << linenum << " Position: " << pos << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: search phrase file+\n";
        return 0;
    }
    const std::string phrase{argv[1]};
    for (int n=2; n < argc; ++n) {
        std::cout << "Searching " << argv[n] << " for " << phrase << "\n";
        std::ifstream infile{argv[n]};
        search(phrase, infile);
    }
}
```

### Omit `return 0`

When a C or C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no need to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

**Note:** when I make this suggestion, it's almost invariably followed by one of two kinds of comments:  "I didn't know that." or "That's bad advice!"  My rationale is that it's safe and useful to rely on compiler behavior explicitly supported by the standard.  For C, since C99; see ISO/IEC 9899:1999 section 5.1.2.2.3:

> [...] a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument; reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0.

For C++, since the first standard in 1998; see ISO/IEC 14882:1998 section 3.6.1:

> If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;

All versions of both standards since then (C99 and C++98) have maintained the same idea.  We rely on automatically generated member functions in C++, and few people write explicit `return;` statements at the end of a `void` function.  Reasons against omitting seem to boil down to ["it looks weird"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581993/what-the-reasons-for-against-returning-0-from-main-in-iso-c/2582015#2582015).  If, like me, you're curious about the rationale for the change to the C standard [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394171/what-was-the-rationale-for-making-return-0-at-the-end-of-main-optional).  Also note that in the early 1990s this was considered "sloppy practice" because it was undefined behavior (although widely supported) at the time.

So I advocate omitting it; others disagree (often vehemently!)  In any case, if you encounter code that omits it, you'll know that it's explicitly supported by the standard and you'll know what it means.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Edward's excellent comments, I'd add a few more points that seem like they might be worth considering.

## Structure data appropriately

Right now you're using a vector of strings to hold all your result data. Then you're going through the strings and finding the ones that correspond to (for example) a file name, and then separating file name(s) from the positions inside a file.

Rather than storing those together (and sorting them back out afterwards) I'd define a structure to hold them more directly:

```
struct hit_record {
    std::string filename;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> hits;
};
```

This way, we can search through a file, and give the name of the file in `filename`, and the record of each matching location in `hits`.

## Associate operations directly with data

We can also add an operator to write out the record of hits in a particular file:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, hit_record const &rec) {
    os << rec.hits.size() << " occurrences found in : " << rec.filename;
    int prev_line = -1;

    for (auto const &h : rec.hits) {
        if (prev_line == h.first) {
            os << ", " << h.second;
        }
        else {
            os << "\nLine: " << h.first << " Position: " << h.second;
        }
        prev_line = h.first;
    }
    return os;
}
```

This way, when we want to print out all the positions for a particular file, we just do:

```
hit_record rec;

// find locations here

std::cout << rec;
```

Then (more or less as Edward suggested) I'd write a function that just looks for locations of phrase in *one* file (and stores them in the `hit_record` shown above:

```
hit_record search_file(std::string const &filename, std::string const &phrase) {
    hit_record r{filename};

    std::ifstream in(filename);
    std::string line;

    for (int line_num = 1; std::getline(in, line); ++line_num) {
        for (int offset=0; 
             (offset=line.find(phrase, offset)) != std::string::npos;
             ++offset) 
        {
            r.hits.push_back({line_num, offset});
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

## Think about how to maximize usability

I'd allow the user to specify the phrase and filename(s) on the command line instead of typing them in interactively (which gets painful very quickly).

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: find <phrase> <file> [file ...]";
        return 1;
    }

    std::string phrase(argv[1]);
    std::vector<std::string> files(argv+2, argv+argc);

    std::vector<hit_record> hits;

    for (auto const &file : files)
        hits.push_back(search_file(file, phrase));

    for (auto const &hit : hits)
        std::cout << hit << "\n";
}
```

## Really *use* the standard library

The library has a lot of *extremely* useful code--really using it (e.g., creating the vector of file names directly from `argv`) can simplify your code a *lot*.

Comment: Nice review.  One nit: rather than `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> hits;`, I'd suggest `std::vector<std::pair<std::size_t, std::string::size_type>>`.  But that's a very minor nit and in most practical situations, there will likely be no discernible difference in operation.

Comment: I waver back and forth on that. My current thinking is that it's best to restrict use of unsigned types to situations where you basically just want a "bunch of bits". Where you're going to do arithmetic, unsigned types are prone to failure, often in spectacularly awful ways.

Comment: Generally, I agree with that.  My thought is that it's useful to preserve the data as it's received or generated and if conversions are required, leave it to the user of the class who might at least get a compiler warning if inadvertently converting from signed to unsigned, for example.  I know that `std::size_t` is guaranteed to be an unsigned type, but I'm not sure that we have that same guarantee for `std::string::size_type`.  Maybe you know?

Comment: I can certainly see an argument for preserving the data as-is. As I said, I waver back and forth on this, largely because there's no one answer that's unequivocally correct and others are wrong. Yes, I believe`size_type` is always unsigned. It comes from the allocator traits, usually coming down to `make_unsigned_t<difference_type>` (but sometimes just a `typedef` for `size_t`). Certainly unsigned for `std::string`, and I *think* required to be unsigned for all other instantiations of `std::basic_string` as well (but the latter is a little more questionable).